# IronPython clr not working with the AutoCAD API's dlls

Tags: c#, ironpython, autocad

The company I work for is switching to Pandas and wants old C# applications rebuilt in IronPython. I'm attempting to convert an AutoCAD automation I built in C# to IronPython I'm getting an error. I'm attempting to use clr to load dlls from AutoCAD's API library.

Reference Code:

```
import clr
path = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk AutoCAD Civil 3D 2014\\"
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + "AcCoreMgd.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + "AcDbMgd.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + "AcMgd.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + "AcMgdInternal.dll")
```

Error:

> SystemError: Could not load file or assembly 'accoremgd, Version=19.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. This assembly was compiled for a different processor.

I'm a little confused because I built the Automation in Visual Studio on the same machine I'm currently using to convert it to IronPython.

Comment: Could there be a x86 vs x64 issue? Are those managed DLLs compiled for AnyCPU or a specific target? Is your IronPython running as x86 oder x64?

Comment: I'm running x64 IronPython with x64 Eclipse and trying to plugin x64 AutoCAD dlls

Comment: I also just tried rebuilding and running it in x64 Visual Studio (the same program where the C# application was built) and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-accoremgd-dll-or-one-of-its/td-p/3615818/page/2 seems to imply that those DLLs might only work hosted from within autocad, which is probably not the case for your ironpython project?

Comment: @SimonOpelt Yeah, I did some more reading and found that the dlls use a lot of custom features that IronPython cannot handle. So I've decided to build a python wrapper Pandas can communicate with, but leave the C# application to do the actual work. Thank you so much for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python (nor IronPython) expert... but indeed the DLLs from AutoCAD install folder are the actual DLLs with all the references. If you get the DLLs from the ObjectARX SDK, at \inc\ folder, then you have a clean reference that will not have secondary references. Download this sdk from www.objectarx.com.

Please not that if you use those DLLs then you must load your app in-process on AutoCAD. Not sure if that can be done with Python (not an expert). I know you can NETLOAD (for .NET apps).

If you're developing a external app that will communicate with AutoCAD, then you should use COM Interop. See the comments at this post: [Trying to read data from a DWG using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseService What DLL do I need to reference to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918833/trying-to-read-data-from-a-dwg-using-autodesk-autocad-databaseservice-what-dll-d/30944295#30944295)

Answer (score 0):

I am using AutoCAD 2015 and instead of loading 'acmgdinternal.dll' I load the following dlls 'accoremgd.dll' and 'acdbmgdbrep.dll' like so

```
#clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + 'acmgdinternal.dll')
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + 'accoremgd.dll')
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + 'acdbmgdbrep.dll')
```

I am not sure if both dlls are needed, so I load them both. I choose them because I use them when I debugging dlls for AutoCAD with C# like PythonLoader and PYLOAD from Kean Walmsley article [here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2009/03/using-ironpython-with-autocad.html)

I hope this helps.