# Trying to read data from a DWG using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseService What DLL do I need to reference to?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, autocad

I have a VB winform project where I am reading data from a table inside a DWG file.
By this method AutoCad needs to be open(**making the application slower**).

I found the article show below where you can use a different approach where you use a Database object(**represent our in-memory drawing**) But I don't know what DLL do I need to reference to be able to use this method. The method use on this appraoch is :

**using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;**   --> need to be able to import

And also the article is from 2006 and on C#. Is there a Better approach now a days ?

Thanks in advance

[Breaking it down-A closernLook at the C# code for importing blocks](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/08/breaking_it_dow.html)

Comment: You've tagged `libredwg`, but mention the Autodesk namespace (you would not do *both* of these). If you are using Autodesk's code (need RealDWG or installed AutoCAD), then reference `acdbmgd`.

Comment: @crashmstr thanks For the answer yes i jus edited my question and deleted the libredwg. Do you know if its faster to use the Database approach as mention on the article than opening loading the drawing in AutoCAD editor?

Comment: If you do not need to interact with the user inside of AutoCAD (such as picking points, etc.), then it can be faster to work directly with the database since you are not loading up all of the Editor and other user interface elements in AutoCAD.

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks for the feedback. I added acdbmgd.dll to my project but when I tried to create a Database object it gives me the error: Could not load file or assembly 'Acdbmgd.dll. Is it true that what I am trying to do is not possible as mention here : [Autocad](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-accoremgd-dll-or-one-of-its/td-p/3615818).

Comment: You might need to set "Copy Local" on or manually copy the DLL to the bin\debug folder, and there are probably other DLLs you need that it depends on (such as `acdbXX.dll` where XX is the version number). There is also a fair amount of other setup and initialization you probably also need to add.

Comment: @crashmstr thanks you so much for still helping. I have set to copy local to true and im trying to fin another articles where they tell you how to set everything up and trying to fix an error when adding acdb19.dll. Thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80938/discussion-between-omachu23-and-crashmstr).

Answer (score 3):

If you create a .DLL that you load inside AutoCAD (with NETLOAD command or with PackageContents.xml/.bundle folder), then you need the following references from AutoCAD install folder:

1. AcMgd.dll
2. AcDbMgd.dll
3. AcCoreMgd.dll (this is required on AutoCAD 2013 and newer)

And make sure all the references are set as Copy Local = false, note this is important :-)

You may have problems with .NET version, so make sure that you have:

- .NET 3.5 for AutoCAD 2010+
- .NET 4.0 for AutoCAD 2012+
- .NET 4.5 for AutoCAD 2015+

And if you choose a older version of .NET, the compiler may throw erros, like cannot use the references. If you are starting, please check at http://www.autodesk.com/myfirstautocadplugin

Now, if you have a external application (.exe), then you cannot use the above, but **only** the COM references (also from AutoCAD install folder)

1. Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll
2. Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll

But for these COM interop you have a different data-model and also a different namespace. Also, this is deprecated, meaning no new features to it.

Comment: Hey @Augusto Thanks for the answer. I am using .NET 4 with AutoCAD 2013  to create a Windows Form, when you click a button you get data from a drawing by using AutoCAD. I am able to do that using  but I wanted to use the Database approach since it seems to work faster. I already Added  The 3 .dll that you mention but the soonest I set the libraries to Copy Local to False I Get the error "acdbmgd.dll must be strong in order to be marked as a prerequisite"  same for accoremgd. Do you think what I need to know to get this to work ?

Comment: the AutoCAD references are not strong signed, that may the issue here... are you signing your DLL? Usually there is nothing special on .NET projects, just make sure you have a "Class Library" with the references as Copy Local false. As you mention database processing, check this post: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/04/batch-process-in-memory-1.html

Comment: When I say "sign" the DLL I mean like in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/k0VFo.png

Answer (score 1):

1. AcDbMgd.dll which stands for "AutoCAD Database Managed" and inside of it are the objects for DWG (aka Database) manipulation.
2. AcMgd.dll which stands for "AutoCAD Managed" and inside of it are the objects with which you can get the Database objects of the current active DWG.
3. Set "Copy Local" to False because AutoCAD carries its own copies of the same DLLs.

You can get the DLLS from ObjectArx Libraries which are [here](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=785550). When you install them there will be the dlls you need.

Look at [AutoCAD`s Developers Guide](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html) examples and explanations for the latest "How to".